# Unwanted rows added to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

When importing excel data and preparing a data frame, somehow unwanted rows are added after a step where I tell R to omit columns that meet a certain condition.

I should have 36 rows, but I end up with 36 rows with the data, and then 210 rows with NA data across all columns. They should not be there of course, as my initial data doesn't have any information in those rows, and in an intermediary step in R the data frame does have just 36 rows.

**Here is the code:**

```
setwd("C:/Users/John/Desktop/School/Afstudeer/Data/Results")

x<-c("permute", "vegan", "xlsx")

lapply(x, require, character.only = TRUE)

sampSet <- read.xlsx2('Taxa_Counts_R_TRANSPOSED.xlsx', 1, endRow=37, 
as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE, colClasses= NA)

sampSetO<-sampSet[complete.cases(sampSet),]

row.names(sampSetO) <- sampSetO$Location
sampSetO[1] <- NULL

sampSetOK = sampSetO[colSums(sampSetO) > 0.1,]

View(sampSet)

View(sampSetO)

View(sampSetOK)
```

So, sampSetO looks good. sampSetOK is a mess. It's only natural to think something is going wrong in this line:

```
"sampSetOK = sampSetO[colSums(sampSetO) > 0.1,]"
```

**This is sampSetO:**

[image: sampSetO_Good]

**This is what I get for sampSetOK (note the amount of entries):**

[image: Unwanted_Rows]

I did a similar line where I had rowSums instead of colSums and that works fine....

So what could be the problem and how can I avoid it?

Comment: This happens when your Excel sheet is not really clean. When you click in a cell, even though there is no value, Excel will "safe" an empty value there. So delete all columns and crows that appear empty on the right and bottom of your actual data, safe the sheet and load the file again.

Comment: @MarkusLnGa This obviously did not work. The sheet was clean, as is evident in how "sampSetO" looks.

Comment: Try changing the line from `sampSetOK = sampSetO[colSums(sampSetO) > 0.1,]` to `sampSetOK = sampSetO[,colSums(sampSetO) > 0.1]`.  If that works it is because you were subsetting the rows when you intended to subset the columns.

Comment: @KerryJackson This works, and you made me understand what went wrong with the code I used.

Comment: `sampSetO[colSums(sampSetO) > 0.1,]` is your problem. `colSums` returns as many values as their are *columns* in your data, but you are using it to filter *rows*. (As Kerry suggested.)